# undefined reference to symbol 'cudaStreamCreate'

Tags: cuda, cublas

Building my project using CMake I get the following linker error and don't know how to solve it. Using `make VERBOSE=1` reveals the generated commands which look ok to me:

```
azg@HPC:~/code/myproject/build_debug$ /usr/bin/c++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Woverloaded
   -virtual  -g3 -ggdb3 -fopenmp CMakeFiles/mymain.dir/main/cpp
   /algorithm/mymain.cc.o -o mymain -rdynamic 
   my_library.a /opt/dev/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /opt/dev/boost      
   /lib/libboost_graph.a /opt/dev/boost/lib/libboost_system.a /opt/dev/boost
   /lib/libboost_program_options.a /opt/dev/boost/lib/libboost_chrono.a /usr/local
   /hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so -lz -lrt -ldl -lm /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so -lcuda 
   /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcublas.so /opt/dev/magma/1.4.0-beta2/lib/libmagma.a  
   /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libimf.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/hdf5/lib:/usr/local/cuda-
   5.0/lib64:/opt/intel/lib/intel64/usr/bin/ld:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcublas.so:
```

and the linker error:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'cudaStreamCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'cudaStreamCreate' is defined in DSO /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The linker error message is telling you *exactly* what to do to fix this. Don't specify shared libraries as files, that passes them to the compiler which ignores them. Use `-l` for each library (ie. `-lcuda` as you are already doing for libcuda). I can't tell you how to do that in Cmake but that is the source of the prolem.

Comment: r u sure that u have the libcudart.so in the path /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so ? Check this because most of the time its /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so

Comment: @SagarMasuti: read the error message. It is there and the compiler is even saying it can find it, but that it should be linked.

Comment: @talonmies : Oops sorry didnt see this line " so try adding it to the linker command line".. +1 for u.. -1 for me :(

Comment: @talonmies can you change the command to what you mean and if it links I will accept your answer. I already tried different things e.g. -lcudart and then the cudartlib file name but does not work. I will then find out how to fix in CMake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker error message is telling you *exactly* what to do to fix this.

Don't specify shared libraries as files, that passes them to the compiler which ignores them. Pass each library search path to the linker with -L and each library stub name with -l. The linker will search for a suitable version of the library (either shared or static depending on what therer is available and the build options you pass) and then link the full list of dependencies together. The resulting build command might look like:

```
c++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Woverloaded \
   -virtual  -g3 -ggdb3 -fopenmp CMakeFiles/mymain.dir/main/cpp \
   /algorithm/mymain.cc.o -o mymain -rdynamic my_library.a \
   -L/opt/dev/boost/lib \
   -L/usr/local/hdf5/lib \
   -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 \
   -L/opt/dev/magma/1.4.0-beta2/lib \
   -L/opt/intel/lib/intel64 \
   -lboost_filesystem \
   -lboost_graph \
   -lboost_system \
   -lboost_program_options \
   -lboost_chrono \
   -lhdf5 \
   -lz -lrt -ldl -lm \
   -lcudart \
   -lcuda \
   -lcublas \
   -lmagma \
   -limf
   -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/hdf5/lib:/usr/local/cuda- 5.0/lib64:/opt/intel/lib/intel64/usr/bin/ld
```

[huge disclaimer: cut and pasted on an ipad on the end of a very flaky GSM connection in the middle of lapland. Not expected to actually work]

I have no idea how you get Cmake to do that, and you haven't shown us a Makefile so that is about as much help as I can offer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I fails with the same error. Researching a bit more seems there is a double-linking issue connected to MAGMA http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=336 MAGMA also depends on CUBLAS

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: In the case that Magma is statically compiled, move it *before* the CuDA libraries. The linker can resolve circular references in dynamic libraries, but static objects and libraries are parsed left to right. If that is the only code using streams, then the stream API code will be discarded by the linker before the static dependency is injected into the graph. Despite the outward simlarity, this isn't the same error as you had before, it is something different....